# comparing a list to another nested list(unorded) and output a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Here is my lists:

```
x = [['Godel Escher Bach', '1979', 'Douglas Hofstadter'], ['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', '2015', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge']]
y = ['2014', '2015', '2014']
```

For example, take y[0] and compare it to x[0][0]~x[2][2] and then print the list(nested list) in x that has the element in y.

This function should compare all the elements in y to every element in x

l have thought about this for 2 days, and l cant figure it out. Please help!

Comment: tell me if l need to clearify something.

Comment: What's the expected output for the given list?

Comment: [['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', '2015', 'Randall Munroe'],['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge']]

Comment: `[xx for yy in set(y) for xx in x if yy in xx]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you'd like to make a list of the books in `x` whose publication date is in `y`. This ought to do it:

```
>>> [b for b in x if b[1] in y]

[['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe'],
 ['Thing Explainer', '2015', 'Randall Munroe'],
 ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge']]
```

`y` probably ought to be a `set` here. The performance gains will be negligible, since `y` is so small, but it being a set conveys how you intend to use it:

```
years = {'2014', '2015', '2014'}
```

Lastly, you might want to use a `namedtuple` from `collections` to represent your books. Something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Book = namedtuple('Book', 'name year author')
books = [Book(b) for b in x]
```

Then the above list comprehension becomes:

```
[b for b in books if b.year in years]
```

which is nice and readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter what you want by using built-in [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter) method:

```
>>> filter(lambda s: s[1] in y, x)
[['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', '2015', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge']]
```

What it does:

It iterates through every list from your `x` list and check if the second element of each sub-list is found in `y[1]`, by using the `lambda` function

**Edit:**

The above code will work if you are certain that the dates in each sub list of `x` maintain the same index, that is `s[1]`,

But in case, you can not guarantee that, then I prefer the next code (I've added other element to `x`, with different date indexes:

```
>>> z = [['Godel Escher Bach', '1979', 'Douglas Hofstadter'], ['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', '2015', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge'],['2015','Thing Explainer',  'Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', 'Andrew Hodge','2014']]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> filter(lambda s: set(s).intersection(y), z)
[['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', '2015', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge'], ['2015', 'Thing Explainer', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', 'Andrew Hodge', '2014']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
list(i for i in x if y[0] in i)

>>> [['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge']]
```

Comment: This is an incomplete solution - what about years that aren't the first element in `y`?

Answer (score 0):

see the clear loop method

```
output = []
for yy in y:
    for xlist in x:
        for xx in xlist:
            if yy == xx:
                output.append( xlist )
                break
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy nested loop problem. Simply iterate through all nested lists in `x` and if the second value is in `y` print it.

```
for nested in x:
    if nested[1] in y:
        print(nested)
```

Or append to a results list and print after the comparisons, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Run through y, checking against x using 'in'

```
x = [['Godel Escher Bach', '1979', 'Douglas Hofstadter'], ['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', '2015', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge']]
y = ['2014', '2015', '2014']
for a in y:
    print("""{}:""".format(a))
    for b in x:
        if a in b:
            print(b)
```

produces:

```
2014:
['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe']
['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge']
2015:
['Thing Explainer', '2015', 'Randall Munroe']
2014:
['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe']
['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge']
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this code: you can run it as a module. it returns a list of coincidences with each item being a list of the index in y and the indexes in x

```
def mifunc(x, y):
    coincidence = []
    for alpha in range(len(x)):
        for beta in range(len(x[alpha])):
            for gamma in range(len(y)):
                if y[gamma] == x[alpha][beta]:
                    coincidence.append([gamma, [alpha, beta]])
    return coincidence


x = [['Godel Escher Bach', '1979', 'Douglas Hofstadter'], ['What if?', '2014', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', '2015', 'Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', '2014', 'Andrew Hodge']]
y = ['2014', '2015', '2014']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    coincidence = mifunc (x, y)
```